# Two DAX Measures Do Not Respect Active Filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a Power BI Desktop Service report. There are two DAX measures that do not respect active filters. These measures are named _LY Qty Sold and _LY Sales. The other measures used in this report behave as expected. I have not been able to troubleshoot this issue.

I have created a .vpax file for this report for your review. Please click [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtoryFmoCy_Qg5Q-QTCUNTrO4MAQYA?e=DGncqJ) to view it.